# Maximum of two random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, self-learning

Say we have two random variables $X,Y$ (that is all we know) and a new random variable $Z = \max(X,Y)$

Those random variables have distribution functions $F^X$, $F^Y$ and $F^Z$.

The question where I'm stuck is:

Write $P(X \leq x)$, $P(Y \leq y ) $ and $F^Z$ down in dependance of $F^X$ and $F^Y$.

Any tips for this problem are appreciated. Full answers discouraged.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $P(Z\le z)=P(X\le z)P(Y\le z)$..  If they are not, then you need information as to the dependency.

Comment: It depends on how X and Y depend on one another, i.e. their joint distribution.

Comment: If you have the joint CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = P(X\le x, Y\le y)$ then you can write $P(Z\le z) = P(X\le z, Y\le z) $ (The max is $\le$ if and only if both $X$ and $Y$ are $\le z.$)

Comment: @herbsteinberg do you have a proof for that theorem ?

Comment: @herbsteinberg nvm I figured it our myself